# Target xml node using attribute, then return value of different attribute using simpleXML

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I have some xml:

```
<release id="2276808" status="Accepted">
    <images>
         <image height="600" type="primary" uri="http://s.dsimg.com/image/R-2276808-1302966902.jpeg" uri150="http://s.dsimg.com/image/R-150-2276808-1302966902.jpeg" width="600"/>                       
         <image height="600" type="secondary" uri="http://s.dsimg.com/image/R-2276808-1302966912.jpeg" uri150="http://s.dsimg.com/image/R-150-2276808-1302966912.jpeg" width="600"/>  
         <image height="600" type="secondary" uri="http://s.dsimg.com/image/R-2276808-1302966919.jpeg" uri150="http://s.dsimg.com/image/R-150-2276808-1302966919.jpeg" width="600"/><image height="600" type="secondary" uri="http://s.dsimg.com/image/R-2276808-1302966929.jpeg" uri150="http://s.dsimg.com/image/R-150-2276808-1302966929.jpeg" width="600"/>
    </images> ...
```

I'm using SimpleXML and php 5.3.

I want to target the `image` node where `type="primary"` and return the value for the uri attribute.

The closest I've gotten is:

```
$xml->xpath('/release/images/image[@type="primary"]')->attributes()->uri;
```

which fails because you cannot call `attribute()` method after `xpath`.

Comment: *Good* question, +1. See my answer for a pure XPath solution -- a one-liner expression that when evaluated produces the wanted value. An explanation is also included.

Answer (score 2):

The pure XPath 1.0 expression to achieve the attributes is:

```
"/release/images/image[@type="primary"]/@uri"
```

May be you have to fix your XPath only.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to target the image node where `type="primary`" and return the
>   value for the `uri` attribute.

**Use this XPath one-liner expression**:

```
/*/images/image[@type="primary"]/@uri
```

This selects the attribute named `uri` of the `image` element the string value of whose `type` attribute is `"primary"`, and that is a child of an `images` element` that is a child of the top element in the XML document.

**To get just the value of the attribute, use this XPath expression**:

```
string(/*/images/image[@type="primary"]/@uri)
```

**Do note**: This is a pure XPath solution and can be used with any W3C XPath - compliant engine.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('feed.xml'));
$theUriArray = $xml->xpath('/release/images/image[@type="primary"]');
$theUri = $theUriArray[0]->attributes()->uri;

echo($theUri);
```

Answer (score 0):

While I'm a big fan of the built-in DOMDocument as opposed to SimpleXML and therefor not all that familiar with SimpleXML...

I believe  `$xml->xpath('/release/images/image[@type="primary"]')` Should give you a list of nodes, not a single node.

In your case, I'd expect a possible solution to be as simple as

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath('/release/images/image[@type="primary"]'); // get matching nodes
$node = reset($nodes); // get first item
$uri = $node->attributes()->uri;
```

Since you specifically mention using SimpleXML, I'd suggest you try looking at the result of your call to `$xml->path(...)`
But for completeness, this is how I'd do it using DOMDocument and DOMXPath (which will work, guaranteed, tested and all):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf8');
$doc->loadXML($yourXMLString);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('/release/images/image[@type="primary"]');

$theNodeYouWant = $nodes->item(0); // the first node matching the query
$uri = $theNodeYouWant->getAttribute('uri');
```

This seems a bit more verbose, but that's mostly because I included the initialization for this one.